Testing framework with a single assertion macro
I usually use the Catch2 testing framework in my C++ projects. Unlike other frameworks, it has only one core assertion macro for all comparisons. Instead of writing REQUIRE_EQ(value, correct); one could write REQUIRE(value == correct);.
I looked up how it was implemented and replicated its core feature. I concluded that I could use macros to extend the TEST(value == correct) to the verify(Decomposer {} <= value == correct, "value == correct") and the TEST(value) to the verify(Decomposer {} <= value). In case of failure now both value and correct would be saved in variables for printing the values instead of the result of comparison.
The expression Decomposer {} <= value == correct first evaluates Decomposer {} <= value which becomes of type UnaryExpression. It has value as its member. Then unaryExpression == correct becomes of the type BinaryExpression. It can compare the value to the correct while having both values as a member. In case of failure, both values can be printed.
I deliberately kept the features to a minimum and probably won't be continuing this project further. I would like to get feedback on

Use of macros. I usually don't use any macros in my programming. The TEST macro is needed when printing variable names. Also like in Catch2 I use macro when generating all operations.
Use of templates and polymorphism. Similar things can be achieved with templates and polymorphism. The other one is static and the other is dynamic. I used expression as a base class instead of having it as a template parameter and I used templates to have any types given into my expression classes.
What would be the next small features that would be important for testing the library? How would you implement them?

Here is the result:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>


const std::string unprintable = "{?}";

template<typename T>
concept Writable = requires(T a) {
  { std::cout << a } -> std::same_as<std::ostream&>;
};


template<typename T>
std::string stringify(const T& value) {
  return unprintable;
}

template<Writable T>
std::string stringify(const T& value) {
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << value;
  return out.str();
}


class Expression {
  public:
    virtual ~Expression() = default;
    virtual bool result() const = 0;
    virtual std::string expand() const = 0;
};

template<typename Left, typename Right>
class BinaryExpression: public Expression {
  public:
    explicit BinaryExpression(bool result, Left left, std::string op, Right right)
      : comparison_result(result), left(left), op(op), right(right)
    {}

    bool result() const override {
      return comparison_result;
    }

    std::string expand() const override {
      return stringify(left) + ' ' + op + ' ' + stringify(right);
    };

  private:
    bool comparison_result;
    Left left;
    std::string op;
    Right right;
};

template<typename Left>
class UnaryExpression: public Expression {
  public:
    explicit UnaryExpression(Left expression)
      : expression(expression)
    {}

#define OPERATOR(op) \
    template<typename Right> \
    friend BinaryExpression<Left, Right> \
    operator op(UnaryExpression l, Right r) { \
      return BinaryExpression { l.expression op r, l.expression, #op, r }; \
    }

    OPERATOR(==);
    OPERATOR(!=);
    OPERATOR(<);
    OPERATOR(<=);
    OPERATOR(>);
    OPERATOR(>=);

#undef OPERATOR

    bool result() const override {
      if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<Left, bool>) {
        return static_cast<bool>(expression);
      }
      return false;
    }

    std::string expand() const override {
      return stringify(expression);
    }

  private:
    Left expression;
};


struct Decomposer {
  template<typename T>
    friend UnaryExpression<T> operator<=(Decomposer, T left) {
      return UnaryExpression<T> { left };
    };
};

void verify(const Expression& result, std::string code) {
  if (result.result()) {
    std::cerr << "pass\n";
  } else {
    std::cerr << "fail:\n"
      << "  got  " << code << '\n'
      << "  with " << result.expand() << '\n';
  }
}

#define TEST(...) verify((Decomposer {} <= __VA_ARGS__), #__VA_ARGS__)


struct Point {
  friend auto operator<=>(const Point& l, const Point& r) = default;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point& point) {
    return out << '(' << point.x << ',' << point.y << ')';
  }
  int x, y;
};

struct Point3d {
  friend auto operator<=>(const Point3d& l, const Point3d& r) = default;
  int x, y, z;
};

int main() {
  TEST(true);
  TEST(1 == 1);
  TEST(1 != 2);
  TEST(1 < 2);
  TEST(1 <= 1);
  TEST(2 > 1);
  TEST(2 >= 2);
  TEST(Point { 1, 2 } == Point { 1, 2 });
  TEST(Point { 1, 2 } >=  Point { 1, 1 });
  TEST(Point3d { 1, 2, 3 } >=  Point3d { 1, 1, 1 });

  TEST(false);
  TEST(1 == 2);
  TEST(1 != 1);
  TEST(2 <= 1);
  TEST(2 < 2);
  TEST(1 >= 2);
  TEST(1 > 1);
  TEST(Point { 1, 2 } == Point { 1, 1 });
  TEST(Point { 1, 2 } <=  Point { 1, 1 });
  TEST(Point3d { 1, 2, 3 } <  Point3d { 1, 1, 1 });
}

Code can be run with g++ -Wall -Wno-parentheses -g -std=c++2a -o testing main.cpp && ./testing to avoid warnings from macros.

This is nice - good job!
I'd move the C++ identifiers into a namespace so that they don't conflict with names from the code under test.
I get a warning from the unused identifier here:

template<typename T>
std::string stringify(const T& value) {
  return unprintable;
}


It's easy to re-write as std::string stringify(const T&).
I would add a couple of extra arguments to verify() so that TEST() can pass __FILE__ and __LINE__ for a properly formatted failure message (so we can jump straight to it in compilation-mode, for example).
We're missing important functionality - there's no way to know whether all the tests passed, so our demo program exits with success code even though some tests failed.  That makes this harder to use in a build system.
